# R error in connecting to NCBI to access protein sequences using "read.GenBank"

Tags: r, macos, ncbi

Im trying to access protein sequence data from NCBI in R using the function read.Genbank:

e.g.

```
ref.proteins <- c("XP_005327622", "XP_026241994", "NP_001107354", " XP_007536378", 
                  "NP_001268234 XP_004712197", "XP_017531808", "PBC34963","BAN21060",
                  "XP_011342207","ACD03812", "XP_009644718", "XP_023982408",
                  "XP_023982408", "XP_006082035", "BAX24454", "XP_026490557",
                  "AAS10175", "BAO58576", "AAM49148") 

read.GenBank("ref.proteins")
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Error in file(file, "r") : 
>     cannot open the connection to 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=ref.proteins&rettype=fasta&retmode=text'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "r") :
>     cannot open URL 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=ref.proteins&rettype=fasta&retmode=text': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'

can anyone help? How do i fix the connection issue?
From what ive read online, it seems to be an issue on mac os?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the quotes around `ref.proteins` in the second line. This works:

```
ref.proteins <- c("XP_005327622", "XP_026241994", "NP_001107354", " XP_007536378")
read.GenBank(ref.proteins)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the protein sequences in a fasta file using the `refseqR` pack.

```
#Dependencies
install_github("jdieramon/refseqR")
library(refseqR)

ref.proteins <- c("XP_005327622", "XP_026241994", "NP_001107354", "XP_007536378")

save_AAfasta_from_xps(ref.proteins, "Downloads/my_proteins")
```